# cell subview duplicating issue in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a custom cell with a badge which display some information.I want to set the badge image and text for some cells only(depends on some flag that i get from web service response). But when i reuse the cell, the badge and its text is getting duplicated. How can it be resolved.

The Badge and its text are a part of the custom cell and not added as subview via code.

```
- (void) setBadgeText:(VBMerchantDealCell *)cell withObject:(VBDeals *)deals{


    if ([deals.dealType intValue] == PUNCHCARDDEAL) {
        if ([deals.punchStatus intValue] == UNIV_INDEX_ONE && ![VBUtility isNullValue:deals.punchSpecialMessage]) {
            [cell.lblBadgeLabel  setText:deals.punchSpecialMessage];
        }else {
            [cell.lblBadgeLabel setText:[self getBadgeTextForPCD:deals]];

        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code? It sounds like you are not reusing the cells properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      // Cell configurations
      [self setBadgeText:indexPath :deals];
      return cell;
  }
- (void) setBadgeText:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withObject:(VBDeals *)deals
  {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    YourTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];]
    if ([deals.dealType intValue] == PUNCHCARDDEAL) 
      {
        if ([deals.punchStatus intValue] == UNIV_INDEX_ONE && ![VBUtility isNullValue:deals.punchSpecialMessage]) 
           [cell.lblBadgeLabel  setText:deals.punchSpecialMessage];
        else 
           [cell.lblBadgeLabel setText:[self getBadgeTextForPCD:deals]];
      }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
  }
```

Comment: i tried this method. Made cells nil when its no longer visible. Is this correct method. Will this create any issues
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound){
       
        VBMerchantDealCell *cell = (VBMerchantDealCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell = nil;
    }
}

Comment: what the purpose of having separate method. have you tried inside cellForRowAtIndexPath itself?

Comment: The table view cell contains a toggle badge which will switch every 3 seconds.During this switching the badge image and the text that is displayed in the badge will change. These are handled in seperate methods.
Currently i cannot reuse the cell as all the cells doesnt contain the same ui elements. So i make the cell nil in didEndDisplaying method. Can anyone tell will this make any performance issue.